# Hibernate and ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL

Tags: oracle, hibernate, ora-01400

I've got fairly simple scenario, one table, one sequence for auto-generating primary keys :

```
CREATE TABLE foo (event_id NUMBER(19,0)....
CREATE SEQUENCE event_seq
```

Part of the hibernate mapping looks like this:

```
...
<id name="id" column="EVENT_ID" type="long">
   <generator class="native">
      <param name="sequence">event_seq</param>
   </generator>
</id>
...
```

Works well without a problem for a long time. But recently I've got this :

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TESTING"."FOO"."EVENT_ID")
```

Would that mean that Oracle failed to generate the sequence number for the EVENT_ID?
**What could be a reason for this**? Apparently this error came from 64bit Oracle, could it be related to a problem? Dropping and recreating the table and sequence doesn't help, it just doesn't want to work on that particular machine. No matter what I do, I can't reproduce this, the error comes from one of the users which is pretty much unreachable.

Any ideas?

**---------------
Problem solved
---------------**

The original issue was detected with Oracle 10.2.0.1.0 64bit while using driver 10.2.0.1.0 on 32bit OS. Once the driver was updated to 11.2.0.2.0, the problem disappeared. It all depends on the VM's if they are running as 32bit or 64bit system.

Comment: Check if the user that connects to the database (as configured in your application server connection pool) has the proper rights to the sequence. If not, then grant them: `grant select on event_seq to <<user>>;`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't automatically generate sequence numbers on table inserts. You either have to code it into the insert, code it into a trigger or have hibernate do it.

I think hibernate needs `<generator class="sequence">` if you want it to do it or your hibernate setup has stopped thinking you are dealing with an Oracle database

Comment: It works fine with the generator I posted originally, but not on that particular machine. EVENT_SEQ index gets created and incremented all right, I tried to fiddle about with permissions like Martin suggested but with no luck - on my end everything just works. I use Oracle 10g express, the problem machine is also 10g but 64bit.., that's the only difference I could tell from the logs so far.